# TFS Extension - TF400813: The user ... is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm developing a TFS extension where I'm trying to access the dashboards Rest API.

The extension has almost all the scopes assigned:

```
  "scopes": [
    "vso.build_execute",
    "vso.code_write",
    "vso.code_manage",
    "vso.dashboards_manage",
    "vso.dashboards",
    "vso.extension_manage",
    "vso.extension.data_write",
    "vso.gallery_manage",
    "vso.identity",
    "vso.notification_manage",
    "vso.packaging_manage",
    "vso.profile",
    "vso.project",
    "vso.project_manage",
    "vso.release_manage"
  ],
```

The below code is making the API call:

```
var webContext = VSS.getWebContext();
console.log(`Collection URI: ${webContext.collection.uri}`);
console.log(`Project Name: ${webContext.project.name}`);
console.log(`User uniquename: ${webContext.user.uniqueName} id: ${webContext.user.id}`);
var baseUri = webContext.collection.uri + "/" + webContext.project.name;
var endpointUri = baseUri + "/_apis/dashboard/dashboards";
console.log(endpointUri);
var authToken = vssAuthentificationService.authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);
console.log(authToken);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: endpointUri,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 'Authorization': authToken }
})
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

which returns:

```
401 (Unauthorized); TF400813: The user ... is not authorized to access this resource
```

If I change the API uri to:

```
var endpointUri = baseUri + "/_apis/build/builds";
```

the response is OK.

The user that's using the extension is a TFS collection administrator.

What kind of permissions/scopes do I need to set in order to have access to the dashboards API?

TFS Version 16.131.27701.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether you have `{team}` in your baseUri, this is required. The rest api should look like below:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards?api-version=4.1-preview.2
```

Comment: How come when I use in a browser https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards it returns the dashboards of the default team?

Comment: From my test, if use Basic auth, it works even there is no `{team}`, but if use oauth token, it requires `{team}`.